# Apache Camel routing API call to message queue

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I have two applications that talk to each other using a REST API.

I would like to know if I can use Apache Camel as a proxy that could "persist" the API calls, for example storing them as messages in ActiveMQ, and then later route the requests to the actual API endpoint.

Practically, I would like to use Apache Camel to "enhance" the API endpoints adding persistence, throttling of requests, etc...

What component do you suggest to use?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by intercepting requests. You can either expose a HTTP-based API via Camel (using either Jetty, Netty, CXF, Restlet, ...; REST DSL) or just invoke a ProducerTemplate in your current HTTP framework and send the data you want to persist to a Camel route. Note further that Camel introduced a REST DSL with version 2.14, though IMO it doesn't really deserve that name as it just exposes a Web API without support for i.e. content type negotiation or mapping support to and from multiple different document formats without digging to deep into the Camel core code.

Comment: You are correct, "intercept" is not correct. The endpoint will be exposed by Camel. What I would like is for this to be transparent to API clients : they should see the same REST endpoint. Of course, if the request is delayed, the response of the request will be different.

Comment: So you want to use Camel to proxy request between client and the already existing API and this way intercept requests/responses and send them to ActiveMQ? It is technically possible to forward each request to an other endpoint and further process requests obtained from such invocations (i.e. persist them). The invoked services need to be either living on a different machine or on a different port though

Comment: What component can I use to dequeue the requests and invoke the endpoints?

Comment: There is unfortunately not one OOTB solution. You may receive a request via i.e. Jetty consumer or directly via Camel's REST DSL. You can then use a queue implementation like Redis or something similar to queue requests and having a further route consume entries from that queue and invoke the remote service. Here you also have multiple options on how to invoke external services. You can use [recipientList](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/routes/HttpInvokerRoute.java#L63) or `.toD(...)` or different methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always try to bridge your HTTP request into a queue, but making the thread wait by forcing the exchangePattern to InOut.

See this example :

```
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleRouteBuilder.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.apache.camel.main.Main main = new org.apache.camel.main.Main();
        main.addRouteBuilder(new SimpleRouteBuilder());
        logger.info("Next call is blocking, ctrl-c to exit\n");
        main.run();
    }
}

class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleRouteBuilder.class);

    public void configure() throws Exception {


        // launching an activemq in background
        final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
        broker.setBrokerName("activemq");
        broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
        Runnable runnable = () -> {
            try {
                broker.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        runnable.run();

        // receiving http request but queuing them
        from("jetty:http://127.0.0.1:10000/input")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger, "received request")
            .to("activemq:queue:persist?exchangePattern=InOut"); // InOut has to be forced with JMS

        // dequeuing and calling backend
        from("activemq:queue:persist")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, logger,"requesting to destination")
            .removeHeaders("CamelHttp*")
            .setHeader("Cache-Control",constant("private, max-age=0,no-store"))
            .to("jetty:http://perdu.com?httpMethod=GET");
    }

}
```

If you are using maven, here is the pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.jschoreels.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-kahadb-store -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. What happens to the parameters passed to the call? Does this work also with multipart POST ?